# Capture all of table's(mat-table) data in a button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I want to capture all of table's data(like all the rows, which may have been modified by the user in the UI from the time table was rendered using `[datasource]="dataSource"` concept).

I initially thought that in `ngOnChanges` I could do something like the following code, but obviously I am missing a point, cause making changes to any row in the table doesn't trigger the following.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {    
    console.log(`--- new data from table ${this.dataSource.data}`);
  }
```

My goal is to basically capture everything inside a table and maybe store in an array, to do something with the data on a button click event. Note - This button is not part of the table.

I was hoping to get all the values of the table using something like `this.myForm.get('selectFormControl')` but I see the table is not part of any form.

Comment: Do you mean that there are input fields in your table? If so, it would be best to define them in your form. Look into using a FormArray

Comment: Hi @robbieAreBest - per row of the table contains a radio button field and a drop down, which could be modified by the user and I am basically trying to make sure whatever data table contains I could grab just all of it and send it for another business logic. May I request you to post some examples as to how to fetch data from a table, in the answer section please.

Comment: would it be a terrible idea to create an id in the table something like `<table id="my-table"> <th></th> <td>  </td> </table>` and in the component.ts class fetch table's information using something like `document.getElementById('my-table')` - for some reason this doesn't feel right.